# Neural Network is not learning a very simple task

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I am a complete beginner in the area. I implemented my first neural network following the online book "Neural Networks and Deep Learning" by Micheal Nielsen. It works fine with classifying handwritten digits. Achieving ~9500/10000 accuracy on the test data.
I am trying to train the network to determine whether $x > 5$ where $x$ is in the interval $[0,10)$, which should be a much simpler task than classifying handwritten digits. However, no learning happens and the accuracy ever the test data stays exactly the same with every epoch. I tried different structures and different learning rates but always the same thing happened. Here is the code I wrote that uses libraries in Nielsen's book:

```
import networkCopy
import numpy as np
# Creating training data
x = []
y = []
for n in range(1000):
    to_add = 100*np.random.rand()
    x.append(np.array([to_add]).reshape(1,1))
    y.append(np.array([float(to_add > 50)]).reshape(1,1))
training_data = zip(x, y)
# Creating test data
tx = []
ty = []
for n in range(1000):
    to_add = 100*np.random.rand()
    tx.append(np.array([to_add]).reshape(1,1))
    ty.append(np.array([float(to_add > 50)]).reshape(1,1))
test_data = zip(tx, ty)

# Creating and training the network
net = networkCopy.Network([1, 5, 1])  # [1, 5, 1] contains the number of neurons for each layer
net.SGD(training_data, 300, 100, 5.0, test_data=test_data)
# 300 is the number of epochs, 100 is the mini batch size
#5.0 is the learning rate
```

The way I generated the data may not be optimal, it is an ad hoc solution to make the data in the proper form for the network. This is my first question so I apologize for any mistakes that might be in the format of the question.

Comment: I don’t understand the point of your task. If you have got it to predict the digit already then why not just add some code that takes the predicted digit and returns `prediction > 5`?

Comment: Yes the task is pointless, I am doing it just to build a better understanding of how neural networks behave. This is the reason I chose the task extremely simple.